# Better way to extract only 2nd column of a txt file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I have a txt file that looks like this. The number part and sentence part is separated by one tab.

```
1234  I'll give 5.
1334  Surprisingly well made.
```

I'm trying to only extract second column (sentence part) and put it into a variable. I could do this by using `.split()` and `.join()` as below

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
for line in f.readlines():
    temp = line.split()
    del temp[0]
    line = ' '.join(temp)
    print(line)
```

Just thought there might be better way to do this that doesn't do
split and join which looks kind of meaningless.. like is there anyway to group up the rest part once it hits '\tab'?

Comment: Why not just `line = line.split()[1]`?

Comment: `.split('\t', 1)`?

Comment: @KlausD. That captures the first part (numbers) too.

Comment: @slider That extracts only the first word of each sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Or kinda easier:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    print('\n'.join(line.split()[1] for line in f))
```

Comment: This is the best answer, but I'll leave mine up as reference

Answer (score 1):

You could slice and use a context manager so your file handler is not orphaned in edge cases.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f
    for line in f:
        print((' '.join(line.split()[1:]))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it separates every word in a sentence like mine. (something like ['Surprisingly', 'well', 'made.'])

Comment: I think you read an earlier iteration of my answer @PuffedRiceCrackers, because I believe I fixed that

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each line always has the second part:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split('\t', 1)[1])
```

If it does not (then skip it):

```
with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            print(line.split('\t', 1)[1])
        except IndexError:
            pass
```